# Congress taking a break and Impeachment

Tags: united-states, congress, impeachment

If congress is about to take a break, what happens with the impeachment inquiries that are going on now? Are they simply put on hold for the next bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Staff attorneys are not taking a break. They will continue to pursue and evaluate evidence, create lists of witnesses to subpoena, prepare documents for the committees, etc. There are six committees involved:

- Judiciary
- Intelligence
- Oversight and Reform
- Foreign Affairs
- Financial Services
- Ways and Means

> The Intelligence Committee was quickly lining up investigative targets. Speaking to reporters on Thursday, Representative Adam B. Schiff, the committee’s chairman, said that the complaint provided a clear “road map” for congressional investigators in the coming weeks and that his committee would work through Congress’s two-week recess that begins on Friday.
>
> [The New York Times - Complaint in Hand, Democrats Aim for a Fast, and Focused, Impeachment Inquiry](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/09/26/us/politics/trump-impeachment-democrats.html)

['We Are Not To Let Momentum Drop': Despite Recess, Impeachment Inquiry Persists](https://www.npr.org/2019/09/27/765085075/lawmakers-head-home-for-2-weeks-but-impeachment-inquiry-rolls-on):

> "I can tell you it's going to be a very busy couple of weeks ahead," Schiff told reporters. The chairman said the committee is scheduling hearings and witness interviews, as well as working on document requests and possible subpoenas.
>
> The Foreign Affairs, Intelligence, and Oversight committees issued a joint subpoena on Friday for Secretary of State Mike Pompeo to compel documents that the State Department has so far declined to turn over to Congress. The committees want State Department records of the president's communications with Ukraine that are now the central focus of an impeachment investigation.
>
> The committee says it will also take depositions over the course of the next two weeks from five State Department officials who have some knowledge of the events that transpired. They are Trump's former ambassador to Ukraine Marie "Masha" Yovanovitch, special envoy Kurt Volker, Deputy Assistant Secretary George Kent, counselor T. Ulrich Brechbuhl, and Ambassador to the EU Gordon Sondland.

The public portion of the impeachment inquiry, primarily committee hearings, will be delayed; but the work will go on.

Comment: @divibisan - I appreciate the quote. nytimes.com is a site I don't go to because I refuse to register.